# jquery with php loading file

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery with a simple php code:

```
$('#some').click(function() {
    <?php
    require_once('some1.php?name="some' + index + '"');
    ?>
});
```

It shows no error, so I don't know what is wrong.

In some1 I have:

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('../sql/config.php');

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $name = clean($_GET['name']);
?>
```

It's not complete because I want to make a sql command (insert).

I want when I click in #some to execute that file (create a entry in the table that isn't define yet).

Comment: ok, neither do we. What's your question?

Comment: Without knowing what's in `some1.php` or what you want the `click(function())` to do, it's difficult to help

Comment: Also try making a title that describes your problem. "jQuery with php" isn't particularly descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do here is make an ajax request onclick to you page like so:

```
 $('#some').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'some1.php?var=' + index,
      success: function(data) {
        alert('success.');
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the function `require_once()` incorrectly.  It [expects a file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php), not a URL.  So the `?name=...` URL parameter that you're passing to it won't do anything (and may break the entire statement).

Being a PHP function, it's processed server-side.  So if that `index` variable is coming from JavaScript code then it won't be known server-side at all.  So whatever you're trying to include, for whatever purpose it serves, will need to be done in a different way.